# Mongo BI Connector to SpreadSheet

Tags: mongodb

I have mongoDB & MongoBI connector installed & configured. Want to check whether the BI Connector is working with a client.

In my case, want to use BI Connector with SpreadSheet. I am using the following URL - https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/connect/excel/

Able to get till Step# 5 (Select Your DSN), as per the document. When I click next I don't see any database (or) table to select. Stuck after step# 5.

Any idea? Need some suggestions/help.

Answer (score 0):

select your created DSN.and you can use it

Comment: Hi Krislie,  
I created DSN & it did not work. Later I figured out the issue & resolved it ..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with 32 bit versus 64-bit driver. In my case, I was using excel 32 bit  & mongo driver installed was 64-bit.

After installing the right Mongo Driver version -> recreate DSN -> follow the steps as per docs -> it worked like a charm :-)

Hope it helpful